# URLs for child terms

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

In my taxonomy I have a child taxonomy, but when I click into that, the URL changes and doesn't show the custom post type products.

so this is what I'm getting

```
directorytemp.test/business_category/clothes/
```

to

```
directorytemp.test/business_category/shoes/
```

when I want

```
directorytemp.test/business_category/clothes/
```

to

```
directorytemp.test/business_category/clothes/shoes
```

Any advice?

I'm using

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args         = get_terms( array(
   'orderby'  => 'name',
   'order'    => 'ASC',
   'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
   'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
) );
foreach ( $args as $arg ) { ?>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <article>
                           <header class="entry-header">
                               <h2><a href="<?= get_term_link( $arg->term_id ) ?>"><?php echo $arg->name ?></a></h2>
                           </header>
                           <p><a href="<?= get_category_link( $arg->term_id ) ?>"><?php echo $arg->description ?></a></p>
                       </article>
                   </div>
<?php } ?>
           </div>
       </div>
```

… to get my child taxonomy.

Comment: What's your code for registering the taxonomy. That's what's relevant here.